# PHP date input format

Tags: php, sql-server, date, format

Created a PHP input form to `POST` dates into SQL query, on the server side we have `0000-00-00` date format but locally we use the `00/00/0000` format, how do get the input form to accept the `00/00/0000` format to be used in the SQL query? By now we force the users to put the `0000-00-00` and it works perfectly but a lot of them are complaining about that!

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<cust>From: </cust><input name="start_date" placeholder=" 0000-00-00" />
<cust>Until: </cust><input name="end_date" placeholder=" 0000-00-00" />
<select name="RegioSelect" placeholder="Choose"><option></option>
<?php

$region = $_POST["RegioSelect"];
$fdate = $_POST["start_date"];
$edate = $_POST["end_date"];

if(empty($fdate)){
    $fdate = '2000-01-01';  
    } else {
    $fdate;
    }
if(empty($edate)){
    $edate = date("Y/m/d");
    } else {
    $edate;
    }
```

We were thinking convert on server side but in that case we can't use dates to compare date ranges. We convert them after retrieving to user's info as follows:

```
$new_fdate = strtotime($fdate);
$FiDate = date('d/m/Y',$new_fdate);

changed '$edate' to date("Y-m-d");
$new_edate = strtotime($edate);
$EnDate = date('d/m/Y',$new_edate);
?>
<input type="submit" value="Select region">
</select></br>
</form>

<?php

if(empty($region)){
    $region = ' ';
} else {?><h4><?php echo $region; ?></h4><cust><b>From:</b><?php echo $FiDate; ?> <b>Until:</b> <?php echo $EnDate; ?></cust>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Convert your form values to ISO 8601 `YYYY-MM-DD` on an immediate basis and verify it's valid. Likewise, when rendering data for the user, use their *locale specific* setting, which may or may not be `YYYY/MM/DD` or something else entirely. It's generally best to presume the client has some arbitrary format that can be represented as a string suitable for `strptime`/`strftime` and the server *must* use `YYYY-MM-DD` for consistency.

Comment: You might find it easier to use PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class wherever possible. It has a `createFromFormat` initialisation method that can accept user input as well as the format used (`d/m/Y`, `Y-m-d`, etc). When displaying again, you use the `format` method to output it however you want.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this as follows, now it works other side around, the input form accept `00/00/0000` date format but get converted to server side once `POSTED`.

```
<form action="list.php" method="POST">
<cust>From: </cust><input name="start_date" placeholder=" 00/00/0000" />
<cust>Until: </cust><input name="end_date" placeholder=" 00/00/0000" />
<select name="RegioSelect" placeholder="Choose"><option></option>
<?php

$region = $_POST["RegioSelect"];
//ORIGINAL VARIABLES
/*$fdate = $_POST["start_date"];
$edate = $_POST["end_date"];
*/
$fdate = date_format(date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $_POST["start_date"]), 'Y-m-d');
$edate = date_format(date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $_POST["end_date"]), 'Y-m-d');

if(empty($fdate)){
    $fdate = '01/01/2000';
    } else {
    $fdate;
    }
if(empty($edate)){
    $edate = date("Y/m/d");
    } else {
    $edate;
    }
```

So the code tells the query to choose all data between `$fdate` and `$edate`, if `$fdate` is empty take `01/01/2000` as first date and if `$edate` is empty take `TODAY()` as end date.